# WebRTC Video Recording (JavaScript, Client/Server)

Tags: javascript, audio, video, webrtc, mediarecorder

I've problem: I need to record video from the webcam in browser. When I use safari, chrome mobile, safari mobile and try to record via MediaRecorder it doesnt work. Are there any free or proprietary solutions, e.g. libs to do that?

Comment: Do you want to record in the browser, or are you ok with running a server that records the video?

Comment: Any method that generates a video file will do.

Comment: Pion WebRTC has an example of saving video to disk https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/save-to-disk

Comment: Cool, thx! I will try it